# Find the number of solutions of $x^{39} ≡ x \pmod {39}$ in the set $\{0, 1 , 2, ..., 38\}$

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to work out a general formula for the solutions of this congruence so that I can find the number of solutions in the set specified.
I tried using Chinese remainder theorem on the fact that the congruence is true for module 3 and 13;

$(x)^{39} \equiv x \pmod 3$

$x^{39} \equiv x \pmod {13}$

Then I used FLT and get to:

$x^2 \equiv x \pmod 3$

$x^3 \equiv x \pmod {13} $

However I tried several ways to work from here to get a general formula, but one of them seem to be correct. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have got $$0;1;12;13;14;25;26;27;38$$

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you did it or enlighten me of how I should proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chinese remainder theorem ensures that $$x^{39}\equiv x\mod 39$$ is true if and only if both $$x^{39}\equiv x\mod 13$$ and $$x^{39}\equiv x\mod 3$$ are true. It is easy to see that $x^{39}\equiv x\mod 3$ is true for every integer $x$ (Just insert $-1,0,1$) , so $x^{39}\equiv x\mod 13$, which is equivalent to $x^3\equiv x\mod 13$ because we can reduce the exponent modulo $12$, unless $13|x$ , but in this case, the equivalence is obvious. So, we have $$13|(x-1)x(x+1)$$, so, we have $$x\equiv -1,0\ \ or\ \ 1\mod 13$$

Now, it should be easy to determine the solutions.

Comment: thank you!!! I am not sure what you mean when you say "we can reduce the exponent modulo 12"; where is this 12 coming from?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem : $x^{12}\equiv 1\mod 13$, so we can replace $39$ by $3$

Comment: I see; also why is the module 3 true for all integers? i tried 5 and it is not satisfied

Comment: @supermc09   $3|5^{39}-5$ is not satisfied ? Or what do you mean ?

Comment: right, it is not divisible when I check

Comment: @supermc09   But it is. Did you perhaps take $39$ modulo $3$ instead of modulo $2$ ?

Comment: so I tried in a calculator $5^{39} \pmod 3$ and then it gives 2, instead of 5

Comment: @supermc09 But $5$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, so everything is fine.

Comment: oops that is a stupid question..sorry about that. thanks very much again!!!

Comment: Hey just a followup question that can you explain why it is true that $x^{39} \equiv x \pmod 3$ is true for all integers x? -1,1 and 0 also satisfy the module 13 case, why doesnt that satisfy all integres?

Comment: @supermc09 Modulo $3$, we only have the residues $-1,0,1$. But modulo $13$ we have $-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6$, so verifying $-1,0,1$ is not enough in this case.